# How include robots.txt in IIS 6 to exclude Bing scan my page?

Tags: iis-6, robots.txt, bingbot

I have a **ASP.NET** aplication, using **Framework 2.0**. It's already publish on Internet. It's deploy in **IIS 6** on **Windows 2003 Server**.

How I can exclude the **Bing** browser scan my page? I use Sensitive data from users, and I can't expose to internet.

How I can include robots.txt in my server? or someone IIS configuration?

Regards!

Comment: 1) Why do you only care about Bing, and not about other bots, too? 2) What kind of "sensitive" do you mean? Are you aware that robots.txt is not a suitable way to *protect* the content? 3) What did you try to add a `robots.txt`, what didn’t work, where is your problem?

Comment: Thanks! i added robots.txt to my site. About Bing question is only in this browser appear private result.